# Artemis - Messages Sync Between Memory & Journal

Tags: activemq-artemis

When reading artemis docs understood that - artemis stores entire current active messages  in memory and can offload messages to paging area for a given queue/topic as per the settings & artemis journals are append only.

With respect to this

1. How and when broker sync messages to and from from journal ( Only during restart ? )
2. How it identifies the message to be deleted from journal ( For ex : If journal is append only mode , if a consumer of a persistent message ACK the message , then how broker removes a single message from journal without keeping indexing).
3. Isn't it a performance hit to keep every active message in memory and even makes broker go out of memory. To avoid this , every queue/topic pagination settings have to be set in configuration otherwise broker may fill all the messages. Please correct me if wrong.

Any reference link that can explain about message sync and these information is helpful. Artemis docs explains regarding append only mode though but may be any section/article that explains these storage concepts and I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a durable message is persisted to disk after the broker receives it and before the broker sends a response back to the client that the message was received. In this way the client can know for sure that if it receives the response back from the broker that the durable message it sent was received and persisted to disk.

When using the `NIO` `journal-type` in `broker.xml` (i.e. the default configuration), data is synced to disk using [java.nio.channels.FileChannel.force(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force-boolean-).

Since the journal is append-only during normal operation then when a message is acknowledged it is not actually deleted from the journal. The broker simply appends a delete record to the journal for that particular message. The message will then be physically removed from the journal later during "compaction". This process is controlled by the `journal-compact-min-files` & `journal-compact-percentage` parameters in `broker.xml`. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/persistence.html) for more details on that.

Keeping message data in memory actually improves performance **dramatically** vs. evicting it from memory and then having to read it back from disk later. As you note, this can lead to memory consumption problems which is why the broker supports paging, blocking, etc. The main thing to keep in mind is that a message broker is not a storage medium like a database. Paging is a palliative measure meant to be used as a last resort to keep the broker functioning. Ideally the broker should be configured to handle the expected load without paging (e.g. acquire more RAM, allocate more heap). In other words, message production and message consumption should be balanced. The broker is designed for messages to *flow through* it. It can certainly buffer messages (potentially millions depending on the configuration & hardware) but when its forced to page the performance will drop substantially simply because disk is orders of magnitude slower than RAM.